# Unit testing dynamic imports in node js using jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage, dynamic-import

Does anybody know how to unit test the dynamic import in node js application. Iam unable to cover the function statement while unit testing using jest.

And the dynamic import statement looks like this:

`fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));`

Comment: Ideally, refactor the SUT to allow you to inject the dependency.  Otherwise, Node module resolution is cached, so if you preload the dependency, then replace/patch it with a mock you will have intercepted the import.  You need to be mindful of restoring the original after the test so as not to leave the mock potentially interferring with later tests.

Comment: You need to include your code in the post, attaching images is hard for anyone to follow.  Did you understand the rest of my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I have included the code in the above section now.

Comment: Do you know why this has been implemented as a dynamic import?  It seems redundant.

Comment: Since the latest version of node-fetch is now ESM only module, we cannot using require statement to import it, if we do so, on executing npm run start, we will get errors, so we have to use dynamic imports like I have mentioned above.
https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/HEAD/docs/v3-UPGRADE-GUIDE.md#converted-to-es-module

Comment: Why can't you use `import fetch from 'fetch'`?  Alternatively, refactor so that you pass `fetch` function into the SUT requiring access to fetch functionality.  Then your tests are able to mock the return value, breaking dependence on the network in your tests.

Comment: If we use `import name from module-name`  for node-fetch,  then it results in `Cannot use import outside module` error while executing `npm run start`, so we should add `“type” : “module”` on package.json.
If we do such changes on package.json, then we cant  use `require` for importing other packages throughout the project.
In order to avoid issues with importing node-fetch as well as continue using `require` for importing other packages, we should go for dynamic import of node-fetch.
As a result, we can get rid of issues with node-fetch import and can use require for other packages.

Comment: Then move the import outside the function you are trying to test. Then pass the fetch function where you need it.

Comment: I could'nt get you, I am having this code on exports.js file, so that it can be referred and used anywhere on the server application.

Comment: You are using module resolution as a dependency injector.  `node-fetch` is your dependency, and your source modules are using `require` to access the definition of `fetch`.  As I said at the top, module resolution is cached, so for testing, you can make an initial request, then patch it. It doesn't matter if you use `require` or `import`, e.g. `const fetch = require('node-fetch'); fetch.default = mock;`.  Subsequent `require`s should load the patched version. There are more sophisticated ways to do this to ensure is unwound for subsequent tests, depending on your testing/mocking framework.

Comment: You should probably review how you are doing dependency injection to improve testability.  It's good practice to make sure that your network calls can be easily replaced with mocks so that you can use canned responses and not rely on external resources for the tests.  So pass the `fetch` function into where the dependency is needed, instead of the consumer asking for it via a mechanism that is hard to intercept.

Comment: Here is an article that explains [how to mock an import in jest](https://dev.to/dstrekelj/how-to-mock-imported-functions-with-jest-3pfl)

Comment: Thank you!!, I'll have a look on it.